# Adding SQL statements inside a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL:

```
DECLARE @HTMLROWS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @FIELDS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @HTMLROWSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @FIELDSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TotalContract VARCHAR(10)

SET @TotalContract = 2
SET @Variable = 1

SET @HTMLROWSSingle = '<h1> This is '+@Variable+' 
  This is a test
   'Case When @TotalContract = 2
          Then 
           @Variable * .50 End
          Case When @TotalContract = 3
          Then 
           @Variable * .67 End '

</h1>'

SET @OUTPUT= '
<table class= "FeeTable">'+@HTMLROWSSingle+'</table>
<br/>'

SELECT @OUTPUT
```

I am trying to run the `CASE` statement so I get the value of it inside the string. I can use `'+@Variable+'` and it gets me the value of it which is 1 inside the string but I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near case statement.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: add alias after each END of CASE and comma after the first CASE Statement to separate the fields

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..can you please show me a sample

Comment: Is this a bad question that I got a negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @HTMLROWS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @FIELDS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @HTMLROWSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @FIELDSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TotalContract VARCHAR(10)

SET @TotalContract = 2
SET @Variable = 1

SET @HTMLROWSSingle = '<h1> This is '+@Variable+' 
  This is a test'+
    Case When @TotalContract = 2
          Then 
            CAST(@Variable as decimal) * .50 End  + 
          Case When @TotalContract = 3
          Then 
            CAST(@Variable as decimal) * .67 End  +'

</h1>'

SET @OUTPUT= '
<table class= "FeeTable">'+@HTMLROWSSingle+'</table>
<br/>'

SELECT @OUTPUT
```

I found the correct way of inserting sql inside a string as shown above. Still I am not sure why I got a downvote as I was just trying to find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Like this (use CONCAT instead of '+', and use Unicode string literals):

```
DECLARE @HTMLROWS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @FIELDS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @HTMLROWSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @FIELDSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX)

Declare @Variable int
Declare @Output varchar(max)
DECLARE @TotalContract varchar(10)

Set @TotalContract = 2

Set @Variable = 1

SET @HTMLROWSSingle = concat(N'<h1> This is ',@Variable,N' 
  This is a test
   ', Case When @TotalContract = 2
             Then @Variable * .50 
          When @TotalContract = 3
          Then @Variable * .67 End ,N'

</h1>')

SET @OUTPUT= concat(N'
<table class= "FeeTable">',@HTMLROWSSingle,N'</table>
<br/>')

SELECT @OUTPUT
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. Getting error that concat is not a supported function..Looks like I have 2008 so it's not supported

Comment: You can use '+' instead, but any numbers have to be cast to strings.  Like `cast(case when ... end as nvarchar(20))`.

Comment: I tried using plus in the example and it works when inserting a variable but I get a error when I use it in for case statement

Comment: That's because you did [thing] that causes [error].

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help David..I got it. Also good point about the cast I included that too.